# Rotate raster (asc) by degree in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, pyqgis

my plugin creates an ASC file that I can load in QGIS as raster.

Sometimes I need to load the raster with an additional rotation.

The only solution I can think is to warp the raster by a custom CRS with an additional rotation.

Is there another smartest way?

**EDIT**
This is the `numpy` array that I have. Actually the `asc` file comes from this array, so all the transformations will be performed on this object.

The code below does not work with this dataset:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[ 40.,  40.,  40.,  40.,  40.,  40.,  40.],
[ 36.,  36.,  36.,  36.,  36.,  36.,  36.],
[ 32.,  32.,  32.,  32.,  32.,  32.,  32.],
[ 28.,  28.,  28.,  28.,  28.,  28.,  28.],
[ 24.,  24.,  24.,  24.,  24.,  24.,  24.],
[ 20.,  20.,  20.,  20.,  20.,  20.,  20.]])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try out something similar to this code:

```
mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()

angle = 30 #it also accept negative values

mapcanvas.rotate(angle)
```

In this case, mapcanvas is rotated 30 degrees clockwise.

[image]

**Editing Note:**

Based in matteo's comment, I propose a new code by using python gdal methods.

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr

layer = iface.activeLayer()

provider = layer.dataProvider()

path = provider.dataSourceUri()

fmttypes = {'Byte':'B', 'UInt16':'H', 'Int16':'h', 'UInt32':'I', 'Int32':'i', 'Float32':'f', 'Float64':'d'}

dataset = gdal.Open(path)

#Get projection
prj = dataset.GetProjection()

band = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)

geotransform = dataset.GetGeoTransform()

# Create gtif file with rows and columns from parent raster 
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")

columns, rows = (band.XSize, band.YSize)

BandType = gdal.GetDataTypeName(band.DataType)

output_file = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/test_copy_raster.tif"

data = band.ReadAsArray(0, 0, columns, rows)

dst_ds = driver.Create(output_file, 
                       columns, 
                       rows, 
                       1, 
                       band.DataType)

new_geotransform = list(geotransform)

new_geotransform[2] = 30 #x pixel rotation
new_geotransform[4] = 30 #y pixel rotation

dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray( data )

#setting No Data Values
dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(0)

#setting extension of output raster
# top left x, w-e pixel resolution, rotation, top left y, rotation, n-s pixel resolution
dst_ds.SetGeoTransform(new_geotransform)

# setting spatial reference of output raster 
srs = osr.SpatialReference(wkt = prj)
dst_ds.SetProjection( srs.ExportToWkt() )

#Close output raster dataset 
dst_ds = None

#Close main raster dataset
dataset = None
```

After running the code at the Python Console of QGIS, I loaded the resulting raster with this view:

[image]

In this case, only new raster is rotated 30 degrees anticlockwise.

Comment: @xunlik thanks for the answer.. However, it is not the solution I'm looking for. With your suggestion the entire map will be rotated (and all the layers in it).. while I just need to really rotate the raster map..

Comment: I proposed a new method that really rotate only the raster map.

Comment: thanks for the new method. I tried it with some existing tiff file and it worked without problems. Anyway, with an asc input file the output is not corrected at all. This means the output is not rotated correctly. Maybe some error with the GTiff conversion method? Thanks!

Comment: update.. I tried your script with just moving the final raster and it works. So it seems that the issue is related only to the rotation. And I really don't understand why it doesn't rotate it.

Comment: I edited the question with the numpy array that does not work for me..

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to comment on the previous thread but my reputation points are not sufficient to do so. 
Xunilk's solution is elegant but only worked for me after replacing this piece of code:

```
new_geotransform[2] = 30 #x pixel rotation
new_geotransform[4] = 30 #y pixel rotation
```

with:

```
rotation=30 # pixel rotation (square pixels)
new_geotransform[0] = geotransform[0]
new_geotransform[1] = math.cos(math.radians(rotation))*geotransform[1]
new_geotransform[2] = -math.sin(math.radians(rotation))*geotransform[1]
new_geotransform[3] = geotransform[3]
new_geotransform[4] = math.sin(math.radians(rotation))*geotransform[5]
new_geotransform[5] = math.cos(math.radians(rotation))*geotransform[5]
```

Thereby explicitly taking into account the data structure of the geo-reference transform (http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html)