# Using georeferencer plugin of QGIS (gdal)?

Tags: gdal, georeferencing, geotiff-tiff, rotate

I need to rotate the tiff image that you can see below (basically, consider that the RED rectangle belongs to the tiff: I want to rotate it so that the RED rectangle aligns with the GREEN one).

To do so I tried to use the georeferencer plugin (gdal). But when I try to align it using transformations like 'projective' or 'linear', the georeferencer acts as if it was working, but the output file cannot be readed anywhere as if it was an empty file (even though it is not).
Could the problem come from the fact that my tiff is quite big (1.7 GB)? (Because the same method worked 2 weeks ago with a smaller tiff)

Is there actually a plugin,a script to run in the python console, or any other (free) software that could help me rotating my tiff?

As I have many tiff to rotate, it would be much faster.

[image: tif that I want to rotate]

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Rotate raster (asc) by degree in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216406/rotate-raster-asc-by-degree-in-qgis)